# Continuity of a special map between topological sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, parametric

Let $B_k \subset {[0,1]^{k+1}}$ and define the map: 
$$
\phi_k:B_k\mapsto C^k[0,1]:(\beta_0,\beta_1, \ldots,\beta_k)\mapsto\sum_{i=0}^k\beta_i b_{i,k},
$$
where $\{b_{i,k}(t)=\binom{k}{i}t^i(1-t)^{k-1},\, t\in[0,1], i=0,\ldots,k\}$ denotes the Bernstein Polynomial basis of degree $k$. Denote $P_k:=\{f\in C^k[0,1]: f=\phi_k(\beta_0, \ldots,\beta_k), (\beta_0, \ldots,\beta_k)\in B_k\}$. Endow $B_k$ and $P_k$ with the Euclidean and the uniform metrics, respectively, denoted by $d_E$ and $d_\infty$. Then, it can be readily seen that the map $\phi_k:(B_k,d_E)\mapsto (P_k, d_\infty)$ is continuous.

Now, let me be not very precise for a moment and define a general map $$\phi:\cup_{k=1}^\infty B_k\mapsto \cup_{k=1}^\infty P_k$$
such that, if $\boldsymbol{\beta}\in B_k$, then $\phi(\boldsymbol{\beta})=\phi_k(\boldsymbol{\beta})$. Which type of (metric) topology shoud I use on the "union spaces" so that the map $\phi$ is continuous? Should I consider $\phi$ as a map between the co-product topological spaces for both $(B_k,d_E)$'s and $(P_k,d_\infty)$? Or it is sufficient to consider the co-product topological space for $(B_k,d_E)$'s
and endow $\cup_{k=1}^\infty P_k$ with the uniform metric?

Comment: Give $B_k$ the metrics $\tilde d(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ where $d$ is the old metric. This doesn't change the topology and bounds your metric by one. Now if you denote the new metric on $B_k$ by $d_k$, defining
$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases} d_k(x,y) & x,y\in B_k\\ 2&\text{else}\end{cases}$$
gives you a metric on $\bigcup B_k$ that respects the topology of the components. Note that $P_k\subset C[0,1]$ and thus you can just give the uniform metric to the union of all $P_k$.

Comment: The tricky thing here is the following. Let $k'>k$. A polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^k\beta_i b_{i,k}$ can be rewritten as $\sum_{i=1}^{k'} \beta'_{i}b_{i,k'}$, for a suitable choice of $\beta_{0}', \ldots, \beta_{k'}'$. If I correctly get your proposal, we would have $d(\boldsymbol{\beta},\boldsymbol{\beta}')=2$ and $d_\infty(\sum_{i=0}^k\beta_i b_{i,k,}, \sum_{i=1}^{k'} \beta'_{i}b_{i,k'})=0$.

Comment: Yes, $\bigcup P_k$ is not a disjoint union. The map $\phi:\bigcup B_k\to C[0,1]$ is however still continuous. If you want it to be injective then you have to take a quotient of $\bigcup B_k$. This may give you trouble with the metric.

Comment: A possibly stupid question: then I could also look at $d$ as a metric on $\overline{B}=\cup_{k=1}^\infty \{\{k\}\times B_k\}$ and $\phi$ as a continuous map from $(\overline{B},d)$ to $(\cup_{k=1}^\infty P_k,d_\infty)$, correct?

Comment: Right, $d$ and $\phi$ naturally correspond to a metric on $\overline{B}$ and a continuous map from $\overline{B}$ to $(C[0,1],d_\infty)$ or $(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty P_k, d_\infty)$.